# Have a valid ESTA on EU passport, dual citizenship of non-ESTA country. Got new non-ESTA Passport. Need new ESTA application?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, esta, us-visa-waiver-program, dual-nationality

I have a valid ESTA on my European Passport, and have a second citizenship of a non-VWP country. By the time I applied to the ESTA, I had one valid non-VWP passport but since then it expired and received a new one recently. Do I need to apply for a new ESTA?

Nothing else has changed since then, only the new passport of my second citizenship.

Comment: Did you submit the passport number of your non-VWP passport in your ESTA application?

Comment: Yes, I added my non-VWP passport numbers in the ESTA application, the most recent one (at that time) and all the expired ones. So this is my fourth non-VWP passport and the ESTA has only the previous 3.

Comment: My understanding is that you need to reapply only if there are changes to the answers for the yes/no questions. But if you are inclined to worry about things like this, the cost of USD 14 might be worth it to you to achieve some peace of mind.

Comment: I will call CBP tomorrow to ask the question and see what they have to say. Giving it a deep thought I think it is not a big deal, in fact, in the Q&A they say that you need to only add the most recent "second" passport even if it is expired, or just your other citizenship if you don't have a passport. Probably they want to know if you are a citizen of specific countries that need higher security clearing.

Comment: I believe you are correct. Please post an answer to let us know what they tell you.

Answer (score 2):

I have just called CBP today, and the guy answered that the next time I renew my ESTA I must include the new non-VWP passport.

Of course the guy insisted that once I get a new passport (linked to the ESTA), I must apply again for a new authorization.

Thank you phoog for the support.